# How to print object values correctly to a DIV using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, object, key, innerhtml

I'm doing a course at Codecademy and many of their beginner courses use the console.log() command to print to the console. I however would like to try using **document.GetElementById(**) and **innerHTML** but it instead of printing out the details of the chosen object, it just prints "[object Object]", whereas console.log() prints the details of the key?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="myfrndDetails"></div>

<script>
var frnds = new Object();
frnds.bill = {
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "Gates",
    phoneNumber: "8778787"
}

frnds.steve = {
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "Gates",
    phoneNumber: "8778787"
}


var frndCard = function(frndName,frndLst) {
    for (var onefrnd in frndLst) {
        if (frndLst[onefrnd].firstName === frndName) {
            document.getElementById("myfrndDetails").innerHTML = frndLst[onefrnd];
            return frndLst[onefrnd];
        }
    }
};

frndCard("Bill",frnds);

</script>
```

Comment: Just use JSON.stringify

Comment: Logging something to the console and converting something to a string are not the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

> but it instead of printing out the details of the chosen object, it
>   just prints "[object Object]",

This is because frndLst[onefrnd] is an object and its `toString` method will print `[object Object]`.

Either use `JSON.stringify(frndLst[onefrnd])` to see JSON representation of this object

Or, replace this line

```
document.getElementById("myfrndDetails").innerHTML = frndLst[onefrnd];
```

by

```
document.getElementById("myfrndDetails").innerHTML = "lastname - " +  frndLst[onefrnd].lastName + " and phoneNumber " + frndLst[onefrnd].phoneNumber ;
```

Comment: Thank you. That's perfect. Your last option was totally on point for my next question. Much appreciated.

Comment: Just one question though. If using the third solution that you suggested would you still use **return frndLst[oneFrnd]** ? Wouldn't that just store the JSON objects?

Comment: Yes, that will simply return the object.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function like this :

```js
var frndCard = function(frndName,frndLst) {
    for (var onefrnd in frndLst) {
        
        if (frndLst[onefrnd].firstName === frndName) {
            var output = '';
            for (property in frndLst[onefrnd]) {
                output += property + ': ' + frndLst[onefrnd][property]+"; <br>\n";
              }
            document.getElementById("myfrndDetails").innerHTML = output;
            return frndLst[onefrnd];
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Worked a charm. Thanks Maria.

Answer (score 1):

It's an JSON array. To print JSON array you hav to use JSON.stringify

```
 document.getElementById("myfrndDetails").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(frndLst[onefrnd]);
```

Or If you want to print Firstname, lastname and phonenumber separetly you need to get value of key using array index like below.

```
document.getElementById("myfrndDetails").innerHTML = "lastname - " +  frndLst[onefrnd].lastName + " and phoneNumber " + frndLst[onefrnd].phoneNumber ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could print it as a `string` using `JSON.stringify` like below:

This would print the whole object as is:

```
 document.getElementById("myfrndDetails").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(frndLst[onefrnd]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the object in string.
See the below code:

```
 <div id="myfrndDetails"></div>

<script>
var frnds = new Object();
frnds.bill = {
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "Gates",
    phoneNumber: "8778787"
}

frnds.steve = {
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "Gates",
    phoneNumber: "8778787"
}


var frndCard = function(frndName,frndLst) {
    for (var onefrnd in frndLst) {
        if (frndLst[onefrnd].firstName === frndName) {
            document.getElementById("myfrndDetails").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(frndLst[onefrnd]);

            console.log(frndLst[onefrnd]); 
            //will print  Object { firstName="Bill", lastName="Gates", phoneNumber="8778787"}

            //return frndLst[onefrnd];
            // this will return [object Object]

            return JSON.stringify(frndLst[onefrnd]);
            // will print {"firstName":"Bill","lastName":"Gates","phoneNumber":"8778787"}
        }
    }
};

frndCard("Bill",frnds);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're attempting to display `frndLst[onefrnd];` you're actually asking for the toString() representation of the Object you are printing.

You can find some info on the above here:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Personally i would suggest **building your own function that performs a pretty print of the object** in cause or go for a rudimental string representation of the object using JSON's `stringify` functionality.

```
document.getElementById("myfrndDetails").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(frndLst[onefrnd]);
```